# SQL join columns between two tables that don't have the same columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I don't know if it's because I don't know enough terminology or if it hasn't been done, but among the wealth of answers I can't find one that addresses my problem. I have two tables, we'll call them table A and table B. Table A has a foreign key that points to a single row in B. I want to select entries in col1, col2, and col3 of A and add to that selection col4 and col5 from B where the row in A has an id column that points to a row in B. e.g.
[image]

I thought this should be easy with an `INNER JOIN`, but I can't write anything that results in anything but a syntax error. I'm pretty new to Sql, but this doesn't seem too difficult. Any help is always appreciated.

NOTE: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, which I'm told is important to know.

Comment: Yes, this is a basic inner join. What is the code you tried that got an error?

Comment: You should read this article. Not only will it help with this situation it is critical to understand joins if you want to retrieve data from any relational database. Joins are the very foundation. Unless you really understand joins you can't proceed any further with your knowledge. https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: It turns out, in case anyone cares, that I was using `JOIN` properly, but I didn't realize you could select from multiple tables at once, so I was trying to join it to another select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inner join

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col1, b.col2
from tableA as a
inner join tableB as b on a.b_id = b.id
```

Comment: I think a.b_id would be the link judging by the schema, no?

Comment: @scsimon is right, it should be `on a.b_id = b.id`, because the key that points to B from A is `b_id`, not `id`. After you change it, I'll accept your answer.